# Get the channel of the Bot? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to know in which discord voice channel the bot is. I only found a way to know in which voice channel the user is with:

```
@client.command()
async def write(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    print(channel)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From the [API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.channel) it's in the `VoiceClient`:

```
@client.command()
async def write(ctx):
    channel = ctx.voice_client.channel
    print(channel)
```

Comment: FYI, you may wanna check if ctx.voice_client is None in case the bot isn't in a voice channel